# Chrome and IE sorts JSON Object automatically, how to disable this?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am using the following JSON to create few checkboxes using JavaScript.

```
{"5":"5.5\" x 8.5\"",
"11":"7\" x 10\"",
"4":"8.5\" x 11\"",
"8":"8.5\" x 14\"",
"12":"10\" x 7\"",
"2":"11\" x 8.5\"",
"10":"11\" x 17\"",
"6":"14\" x 8.5\"",
"9":"17\" x 11\""})
```

The JavaScript to create those checkboxes is:

```
for(id in dimensions) {
    $("#the_dimensions").append('<label class="checkbox">' + 
                                '<input type="checkbox" class="dimensions-filter" value="' + id + '">' +
                                dimensions[id] + '</label>');
}
```

On Firefox, the checkbox is created as per the order in the JSON object. So, "5":"5.5\" x 8.5\"" becomes the first element, "11":"7\" x 10\"" becomes the second element, so on.

But on Chrome and IE, the JSON object gets sorted automatically in an ascending order of keys. So, "2":"11\" x 8.5\"" becomes the first element, "4":"8.5\" x 11\"" becomes the second element, so on.

How can I disable auto sorting on Chrome and IE?

Comment: Javascript objects are not ordered. Therefore they cannot be sorted.

Comment: If you want to ensure order, use an array of objects, e.g., `[{"5":"5.5\" x 8.5\""},
{"11":"7\" x 10\""},...]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordered JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993645/ordered-jsonobject)

Comment: Thank you all for comments. While I was trying to use your suggestions, I found an alternate way to solve my problem. I replaced id with name and vice versa. As I sort by name, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

Same Problem here. My JSON-object looks like this:

```
{
  "15" : { "name" : "abc", "desc" : "Lorem Ipsum" },
  "4"  : { "name" : "def", "desc" : "Foo Bar Baz" },
  "24" : { "name" : "ghi", "desc" : "May be" },
  "8"  : { "name" : "jkl", "desc" : "valid" }
}
```

The object is sorted by name at server (A-Z glossary) and I want to render a list with:

```
var data = myObject, i;

console.log(data);

for (i in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Chrome logs:

```
Object {4: Object, 8: Object, 15: Object, 24: Object}
```

and my for-in loop results in wrong sort. It's automatically sorted by the browser, but I need the IDs.

**My solution:**
I decided to change the keys with a prefixed underscore. My object looks now:

```
{
  "_15" : { "name" : "abc", "desc" : "Lorem Ipsum" },
  "_4"  : { "name" : "def", "desc" : "Foo Bar Baz" },
  "_24" : { "name" : "ghi", "desc" : "May be" },
  "_8"  : { "name" : "jkl", "desc" : "valid" }
}
```

And Chrome logs now:

```
Object {_15: Object, _4: Object, _24: Object, _8: Object}
```

And my list is rendered correct.

Comment: I also had a similar issue, and I solved it by adding empty space instead of underscore (" 15": "abc", " 8": "cde", ...) so you don't need to manually remove the underscore

Comment: It does not work anymore, any new workaround?

Comment: @MuditGulgulia tested on latest version of chrome and do not see any difference. The workaround are still working.

Comment: @RWAM don't work for me, I used " and then removed it from frontend