# JSON response to client is taking ascending order by default

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have prepared an array in php with descending order, converted into json_encode. But in client side, I am getting output in ascending order.

Can anyone please help me how can I send with descending order to client.

Array is like

```
Array('code' => '1', 'data' => Array('10' => "Test1", '3' => 'Test2', '1' => 'Test3'))
```

and JSON Output is like

```
{'code' : '1', 'data' : {'1' : 'Test3', '3' : 'Test2', '10' : 'Test1'}}
```

Comment: what is your code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: [Working fine for me](https://eval.in/457648)

Comment: foreach ($MyArray as $key => $MyDetails) {
                         $MyData[$MyDetails['id']] = $MyDetails['test_data'];
                     }

print_r(json_encode(array('code' => '1', 'data' => $MyData)));

Comment: I am using Slim Framework(REST API Framework for PHP). is there any problem while sending data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as i understand it, you want to sort your `$arr['data']` by key?

this can be done via **[ksort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ksort.php)**

```
$arr = Array('code' => '1', 'data' => Array('10' => "Test1", '3' => 'Test2', '1' => 'Test3'));
//ksort will sort the array depending on the key
ksort($arr['data']);
print_r($arr);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

result would be

```
Array
(
    [code] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test3
            [3] => Test2
            [10] => Test1
        )

)
{"code":"1","data":{"1":"Test3","3":"Test2","10":"Test1"}}
```

Live example **[here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a527fa5c2bd7a302203fb6ba6303d58ad483d17)**

Answer (score 1):

It's automatically sorted by the browser, so to keep order you got 2 solutions:

1. You can encode array `data` first, then encode `result` array later

```js
$data = [
    '10' => "Test1",
    '3'  => 'Test2',
    '1'  => 'Test3'
];

$result = [
    'code' => '1',
    'data' => json_encode($data)
];
```

2. You need change index of array `data`, you can add `_` before each key or anything else to change it to string.

```js
$result = [
    'code' => '1',
    'data' => [
        '_10' => "Test1",
        '_3'  => 'Test2',
        '_1'  => 'Test3'
    ]
];
```

and then you will get

```js
{
    "code": "1",
    "data": 
    {
        "_10": "Test1",
        "_3" : "Test2",
        "_1" : "Test3"
    }
}
```

Solution 2 I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806551/5493005