# ng-repeat is not printing based on the order of the json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, servicenow

I have a table that is being printed in the incorrect order based on the JSON.

The table looks like below, i want it to be in the order of the JSON:

why does ng-repeat not print it as it finds it. This is being developed in the ServiceNow platform.

This data is completely dynamic, headers and data can change depending on the table that is chosen or what headers are picked.

### **Assignment group  | Number    | Short description  | Created**

Company Level 1      INC0039473 No access to email  01/02/2019 02:54:26

Company Level 2     INC0039474  This Incident is for SQL daily admin and pro-active checks. 01/02/2019 07:00:07

Company Level 2     INC0039475  Suspicious email    01/02/2019 07:14:05

Company  Level 1    INC0039476  remove mailbox access   01/02/2019 07:30:51

Company Level 1     INC0039477  PDC - LogicMonitor - Server Offline 01/02/2019 08:25:56

Company Level 1     INC0039479  Unable to login to citrix   01/02/2019 08:44:21

HTML

```
<div ng-if="reportDetails.isList">
        <table class="etable" >
          <tbody>
            <tr class="eborder">
              <th ng-repeat="(key, data) in reportDetails.values[0]">{{key}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, data) in reportDetails.values">
              <td ng-repeat="rows in reportDetails.values[key]">{{rows}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

JSON DATA

```
"values":[
{
"Number":"INC0039473",
"Assignment group":"Company Level 1",
"Created":"01/02/2019 02:54:26",
"Short description":"No access to email"
},
{
"Number":"INC0039474",
"Assignment group":"Company Level 2",
"Created":"01/02/2019 07:00:07",
"Short description":"This Incident is for SQL daily admin and pro-active checks."
},
{
"Number":"INC0039475",
"Assignment group":"Company Level 2",
"Created":"01/02/2019 07:14:05",
"Short description":"Suspicious email"
},
{
"Number":"INC0039476",
"Assignment group":"Company Level 1",
"Created":"01/02/2019 07:30:51",
"Short description":"remove mailbox access"
},
{
"Number":"INC0039477",
"Assignment group":"Company Level 1",
"Created":"01/02/2019 08:25:56",
"Short description":"PDC - LogicMonitor - Server Offline"
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag with with AngularJS instead of Angular?

Comment: Do you want you output to be like
INC0039473  Company Level 1

Comment: Chrome change json to be displayed in alphabet order

Comment: @IsraGab its not alphabetic if i add more headers they are in a random order

Comment: @AjinkyaDhote yes order should be INC0039473 Company Level , but it should be what ever order the JSON is in Number, Assignment Group, Created On, Assigned To

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordered JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993645/ordered-jsonobject)

Answer (score 1):

**It does.**

But `ng-repeat` should be used to **run over arrays, not over JSON**.

When you write:

```
 <th ng-repeat="(key, data) in reportDetails.values[0]">{{key}}</th>
```

`reportDetails.values[0]` is a JSON.

Because **Assignement** starts with `a` and **Number** with `N`, Assignement will be displayed first.

The solution would be to have separate array for metadata.
Check for example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mphy59d8/1/)

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606640/chrome-and-ie-sorts-json-object-automatically-how-to-disable-this/15806551) (looks like yours). Answer also is a good work around.

Comment: when i add other columns it comes out in this order

Assignment group Number Short description Created

Comment: Look at this fiddle you will see it's alphabetic order: https://jsfiddle.net/mphy59d8/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.
To render columns dynamically I will suggest processing your json to get the exact order in an array and use it or simply you can hardcode the column if that's not an issue for you

```
<div ng-if="reportDetails.isList">
    <table class="etable" >
      <tbody>
        <tr class="eborder">
          <th >Number</th>
          <th>Assignment group</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, data) in reportDetails.values">
          <td ng-repeat="rows in reportDetails.values[key]">{{rows.Number}}{{rows["Assignment group"]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```