# jQuery $.map with index and value

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, key

Currently, I map my JSON file like this:

```
var sortedData = $.map(response.data, function(data, index) {
    return [data];
});
```

This works fine. But the key (index) is missing. How can I add it?

Content of the JSON file:

```
{
    "index": 5,
    "timestamp": 1570438008,
    "data": {
        "12": [
            "Title 2",
            "Description 2"
        ],
        "10": [
            "Title 1",
            "Description 1"
        ]
    }
}
```

After $.map I'd like to sort it (data attribute). I did it like this:

```
sortedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (b[3] < a[3]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Expected output:

```
"12": [
    "Title 2",
    "Description 2"
],
"10": [
    "Title 1",
    "Description 1"
]
```

.. and NOT like this:

```
"10": [
    "Title 1",
    "Description 1"
],
"12": [
    "Title 2",
    "Description 2"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `[data]` which return you the value of key `data`, instead you should return only `data` which will return value of all keys including index.

```js
var jsonContent = {
    "index": 5,
    "timestamp": 1570438008,
    "data": {
        "12": [
            "Title 2",
            "Description 2"
        ],
        "10": [
            "Title 1",
            "Description 1"
        ]
    }
};
var sortedTicketsDesc = $.map(jsonContent, function(data, index) {
    return data;
});
console.log(sortedTicketsDesc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked BUT I can't sort the content (data) now. I used sortedTicketsDesc.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (b[3] < a[3]) ? -1 : 1;
      });

Comment: can you post your sorting code and on which attribute you are sorting and what is expected output?

Comment: Before I changed my code to your solution, the sorting part worked fine too.

Comment: Error: sortedTicketsDesc[2].sort is not a function

Comment: jsonobject does not preserve the sorting order on most of the browser and it sorts automatically by its alphabetical order. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606640/chrome-and-ie-sorts-json-object-automatically-how-to-disable-this  and https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/727