# Define fixed sort order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I haven't found something in my research so I thought someone can help me here.

My problem is that I want to sort an array of objects which contains a status:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "status":"NEW"
        },
        {
            "status":"PREP"
        },
        {
            "status":"CLOS"
        },
        {
            "status":"END"
        },
        {
            "status":"ERR"
        },
        {
            "status":"PAUS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to set a fixed sort order like all objects with the status "END" coming first then all objects with the status "PREP" and so on.

Is there a way to do that in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). (The documentation says it all).

Comment: try groupBy from underscoreJS. http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy OR try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592799/object-array-group-by-an-element

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a pretty simple comparison operation using a standard `.sort()` callback:

```
var preferredOrder = ['END', 'ERR', ..];
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return preferredOrder.indexOf(a.status) - preferredOrder.indexOf(b.status);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object with their order values and sort it then.

```js
var obj = { "data": [{ "status": "NEW" }, { "status": "PREP" }, { "status": "CLOS" }, { "status": "END" }, { "status": "ERR" }, { "status": "PAUS" }] };

obj.data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var ORDER = { END: 1, PREP: 2, PAUS: 3, CLOS: 4, ERR: 5, NEW: 6 };
    return (ORDER[a.status] || 0) - (ORDER[b.status] || 0);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Key lookup is indeed more efficient than my `indexOf`... :)